# Custom Protocol with Scapy

Tags: python, scapy

Is it possible to add packet number as a new layer in scapy?
Eg:
Pseudo code:

```
for i in range(0,10):

 packet = packet number/Ether()/IP()/"payload"
 send(packet)
```

Comment: If your intention is to keep track of the packets use this                           `Ether()/IP()/UDP()/Raw(load="1")`

Comment: @rabhis I want to keep a track of packets but at the same time have some meaningful payload. The packet number is required by the switch to route the packet to different ports.Switch won't be able to peek at the data.So it has to be done somewhere between layer 4 and layer 2 I think